# POST Multiple Parameters to WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to understand WCF, so my questions may be dumb. I believe I have a firm understanding of "GET" operations. I'm now working on some "POST" operations. My question is, can I write a WCF Service operation, with WebInvoke, that accepts multiple parameters? Or, when I POST data, will it only accept a single serialized parameter?

Thank you!

Comment: this smells like a second version of your previous question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but your POST will have to be passed in using a common understanding of the data, aka a "data contract".

In WCF, the typical approach here is that you'd create a contract class (just an off-my-head example, not 100% working))

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://yournamespace.com")]
public class MyContract
{
   [DataMember(Order=1)]
   public string MyData1 { get(); set{};}

   [DataMember(order=2)]
   public string MyData2 { get(); set{};}

}
```

Then you'd specify your WCF operation to accept that contract type as its parameter

```
[WebInvoke(method="POST")]
public string DoSomethingFromPost(MyContract postedData)
{
}
```

On your client, you'd serialize the data to an xml/json that matches your contract.  Again, loose example:

```
<MyContract xmlns="http://yournamespace.com">
<MyData1>value</MyData1>
<MyData2>value</MyData2>
</MyContract>
```

When the contract matches, WCF will deserialze your POST into your contract object, at which point you can use it like any other class.

Comment: A closing square bracket is missing from the first piece of sample code

Answer (score 7):

It seems like there is a bit of confusion between wcf (which is the name given to microsofts overall abstraction for network programming) and a specific protocol [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), that defines verbs like "POST" and "GET", that wcf will be using to communicate.

When you define a wcf service operation and attribute it with [WebInvoke] you are going to access to the service using REST over HTTP. See [webinvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.aspx) for more detail, however the remarks sum it up well

> The WebInvokeAttribute attribute is
>   applied to a service operation in
>   addition to the
>   OperationContractAttribute and
>   associates the operation with a
>   UriTemplate as well as an underlying
>   transport verb that represents an
>   invocation (for example, HTTP POST,
>   PUT, or DELETE). The
>   WebInvokeAttribute attribute is a
>   passive operation behavior (the
>   IOperationBehavior methods do nothing)
>   that adds metadata to the operation
>   description. Applying the
>   WebInvokeAttribute attribute to a
>   service operation has no effect unless
>   a behavior that looks for this
>   metadata in the operation description
>   (such as WebHttpBehavior) is added to
>   the service's behavior collection. The
>   WebInvokeAttribute determines what
>   HTTP method that a service operation
>   responds to. By default, all methods
>   that have the WebInvokeAttribute
>   applied respond to POST requests.

Also further down the article defines how to map values to your service contract. Something like..

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Mod?x={x}&y={y}")]
long Mod(long x, long y);
```

**EDIT:** To make this a bit more informative for people new to the field.

- an [intro into REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction) without going into platform specifics.
- and a how to set up a simple [REST style wcf service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/RESTEnabledService05122009034907AM/RESTEnabledService.aspx) using wcf

Comment: since Taylor covered the POST body, heres access via the Uri

Comment: +1, Good addition, forgot this.  I typically avoid POSTing via query string for no good reason, but in many situations this is equally appropriate

Comment: Can you combine the two methods? e.g. a method with the URI of Mod?x={x}&y={y} which has post data in the form of SomeObject? So the signature would look something like: long Mod(long x, long y, SomeObject data)