# WCF POST C# get all the input parameters NULL

Tags: c#, wcf, post

I have a WCF REST POST GetConsoTable with multiple input parameters :

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    List<WsConso> GetConsoTable(ConsoDataPhaseParams listPhases , ConsoDataPerimetreParams 
   listPerimetres , ConsoDataVarianteParams listVariantsame, ConsoDataCurrencieParams listCurrencies);
```

And the parameters are the same : all are List of string , for exemple Paramaeter : ConsoDataPhaseParams

```
 [DataContract]
 public class ConsoDataPhaseParams 
 {
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ListPhases { get; set; }

 }
```

Here is the implementation of the service wcf:

```
public List<WsConso> GetConsoTable(ConsoDataPhaseParams consoDataPhaseParams, ConsoDataPerimetreParams consoDataPerimetreParams, ConsoDataVarianteParams consoDataVarianteParams, ConsoDataCurrencieParams consoDataCurrencieParams)
    {
        CommonParams commonParams = null;     
        var lstConsosData = consoServices.GetConsoTableMapped(consoDataPhaseParams, consoDataPerimetreParams, consoDataVarianteParams, consoDataCurrencieParams);

       // ...
    }
```

My problem when I call this service with Postman and I enter all the input :

```
{   
"ListPhases" : [ "B", "C", "D"] ,
"ListPerimetres": ["GLOBE"],
"ListVariants" : ["1", "2", "3", "66" ],
"ListCurrencies" : ["EUR", "UD" ]
}
```

When I debug my service, I get all the parameters are NULL !!
I din't know what is the problem exact?

However I havr other wcf REST POST :

```
  public List<WsConso> GetConsosByName(ConsoNameParams consoNameParams)
    {
       //...
    }
```

The ConsoNameParams class:

```
[DataContract]
public class ConsoNameParams 
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ListNames { get; set; }
}
```

and To call it in POSTMAN:

```
{   
   "ListUserName": ["ADMINCONSOLE","WEBSERVICE"]
 }
```

And it works correct !!
Then The problem I guess with multiple input parameters.

So can I fix it ? Thanks,

Comment: Try sending your input as an array to your webservice method.

Comment: @RahulSharma I edit my post with other exemple success

Comment: Thanks, I know this solution , but it is for the multiple parameters for WCF GET , I have WCF POST

Comment: Sorry, for POST, this question will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913953/post-multiple-parameters-to-wcf-service

Comment: Unfortunately, always I have NULL! It is weired ! I don't understand how get this NULL however I have values of parameters

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks a lot for your help, I find the solution finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.
First I create just one class and all of the  list if strings in this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class ConsoDataPhaseParams : CommonParams
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ListPhases { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ListPerimetres { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ListVariants { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ListCurrencies { get; set; }

}
```

Then I changed the BodyStyle to Bare:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]      
    List<WsConso> GetConsoTable(ConsoDataPhaseParams consoDataPhaseParams);
```

And now it works fine ! and I have the values of my input parameters